# Hardware Accelerating in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, hardware-acceleration

Is there a way to force hardware accelerating in a ListView.
I have a ListView with more than 400 items with an icon an scrolling is very slow. Each Item has the same icon. I also added a ViewHolder. 
In manifest file i enabled Hardware Accelerating.
An when i run this code:

```
ListView list_new = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview01);
list_new.isHardwareAccelerated();
```

It returns false.
My phone is a Nexus S with Jelly Bean.
How can i force Hardware Accelerating?

**EDIT:**
Here is my ListView:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:persistentDrawingCache="scrolling"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true" 
    android:scrollingCache="true" 
    android:smoothScrollbar="true" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's the best thing to do. But you could expose us your list code so that we could optimize it

Comment: Also, hardware acceleration is not a magical spell that renders everything smooth. In many cases not using hardware acceleration yields a better result.

Comment: i now that hardware acceleration can't remove the slowness. But i think that it can improve that. I will post the Code soon.

Comment: can you optimize anything in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Not all View suport hardwareAccelerated. HardwareAccelerated use for draw on Canvas. For ListView use

```
<ListView
...
android:smoothScrollbar="true";
...
>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your listview
    `android:layerType="hardware"`